# What is the difference between installing a package in my Windows CMD and in VS Code terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command

I am doing this project where i need to install a package called Twint.
I want to install this package and use it's commands in my VS Code.

What happends when i for example type this in my Windows CMD?

pip3 install --user --upgrade git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint

Because i can't type this in my VS code terminal, where i usually install packages with pip.

It will return an error that says ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?''

Now if i run this in my Windows Command it seems that i can't directly import the package in VS code?
Can anyone help me out with this confusion, where does the files get stored and how do i create good habbits around installing packages?

Hope someone understands what im struggeling with here.
Best

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that computers have more than one version of python installed and that editors like VS code use a different version than `pip` uses on the command line. `pip` installs packages where the version of python it is linked to expects them to be, but VScode doesn't know to look there.

It sounds like you have `git` installed where `pip` installs things, so you can upgrade from the command line without issue, but there's no installation of `git` where VScode is looking, so there's nothing to upgrade.

You either need to find where `pip` installs things and add it to the $PATH VScode uses, or try running a variation of `python -m pip install --user git` (specifying a specific url, or other things, as needed) from within VScode, which will ensure the package gets installed in a place that VScode looks for packages.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install git in your windows from here:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then add its installation bin path to your windows's environment path. Then you will find the git command at the command prompt globally.

This may solve you problem.